# Intercepting based on HTTP header in RESTeasy

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, resteasy

I am developing REST services with two types.

- before login no session token will be passed to HTTP header.
- after login session token will be passed in each request.

I dont want to include @HeaderParam in each and every REST method. I want to intercept it first and based on that I want to check the validity of session. Please let me know

1. how I can intercept based on headers in RESTEasy
2. How to avoid intercepting few methods

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I solved this problem using PreProcessInterceptor

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface Securable {
  String header() default "session-token";
}

@Provider
@ServerInterceptor
public class ValidationInterceptor implements PreProcessInterceptor, AcceptedByMethod {

  @Context
  private HttpServletRequest servletRequest;

  @Override
  public boolean accept(Class clazz, Method method) {
    return method.isAnnotationPresent(Securable.class);
  }

  @Override
  public ServerResponse preProcess(HttpRequest httpRequest, ResourceMethod resourceMethod) throws Failure,
      WebApplicationException {

    Securable securable =  resourceMethod.getMethod().getAnnotation(Securable.class);
    String headerValue = servletRequest.getHeader(securable.header());

    if (headerValue == null){
      return (ServerResponse)Response.status(Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity("Invalid Session").build();
    }else{
      // Validatation logic goes here
    }

    return null;
  }
}
```

The annotation @Securable will be used on REST service which needs to be validated.

```
@Securable
@PUT
public Response updateUser(User user)
```

Comment: If you are using Jersey then create an annotation 'x' and in the annotation mention @NameBinding. Create ContainerRequestFilter and add annotation 'x' to this filter. Now decorate your services with 'x' annotation

Answer (score 4):

There are two approaches

1. Use [JAX-RS interceptors](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/1.1.GA/userguide/html/Interceptors.html) - you have access to request object in the interceptor, so you can read headers
2. Use good old JavaServlet Filters - it is not a problem that you are using JAX-RS, you can filter REST requests as well. Similarly to interceptors, filters have access to request object, which has header information

In both cases you can check if HttpSession exists (`request.getSession()` method) and it has required attribute.

You can include/exclude requests filtered either in configuration or programatically in Java code, looking at request path.